# I misuderstand why doesn't work and how to fix it?

Tags: php

My exercise is to place all the characters in alphabetical order first, then numbers, and finally all the other characters, each in the following 3 groups following the ASCII order.
It would be like

```
./ssap.php toto tutu 4234 "_hop A2l+ XXX" ## "1948372 AhAhAh"
AhAhAh 
A2l+
toto 
tutu
XXX 
1948372
4234 
##
_hop
```

Comment: What exactly is happening right now. What is the output now and what exactly do you want to happen.

Comment: I need this answer: AhAhAh 
A2l+
toto 
tutu
XXX 
1948372
4234 
##
_hop

Comment: my code is executed as following: 4234
A2l+
XXX
_hop
toto
tutu

Comment: I've solved that like that 
```
#!/usr/bin/php
<?php
function ft_split($string){
    $delimiter = " ";
    $newstr = explode ($delimiter, $string); 
    sort($newstr);
    return $newstr;
}

if ($argc < 2)
    exit;
$ar = array();

for ($i = 1; $i < $argc; $i++){
  $ar2 = ft_split($argv[$i]);
  $ar = array_merge($ar2, $ar);
}
asort($ar);
foreach($ar as $value){
echo "$value\n";
}
?>
```
However I cannot recieve the exact answer. Perhaps "##" interferes for my code.

Comment: `#` is a comment. It's not part of the string.

Comment: #is not a comment in my case

Comment: Yes, it is. Why do you think it is not? The string ends after `XXX`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot do it with simple `asort`, replace it with `uasort`.

This is a hint for a possible approach, you can finish that by adding more conditions (see the comment inside):

```
uasort($ar, function($a, $b) {
    if(ctype_alpha(substr($a, 0, 1)) && is_numeric(substr($b, 0, 1))) {
        echo "comparing $a $b\n";
        return -1;
    }
    if(ctype_alpha(substr($b, 0, 1)) && is_numeric(substr($a, 0, 1))) {
        echo "comparingx $a $b\n";
        return 1;
    }

    // add more code here to compare words with non-alphanumeric characters
    // and other custom conditions if you find some issues

    return ($a < $b) ? -1 : 1;
});
```